# What is the best way to deal with `rm`?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-fusion

my situation is quite unique:

1. I am using a macbookpro and running VMFusion for Ubuntu
2. I am sharing a particular folder between ubuntu and mac via "Shared Folders"
3. As you all know, this means that my folder will be mounted to my kernel at /mnt/hgfs/

I am a pretty careless person and I have always aliased rm=gvfs-trash. I realized that for mounted partitions, '/mnt/hgfs/.Trash-501' (the normal location of trash folders on each parition) does not exist. I have tried using both rm=gvfs-trash and rm=trashput and they seem to be encountering the same error.

What's a good fix for this?

(I am contemplating symlinking /home/disappearedng/.local/share/Trash to /mnt/hgfs/.Trash-501 but then I am encountering an error `ln: creating symbolic link`./Trash': No such file or directory` which I have no reason why. )

EDIT: I am not here to debate whether I want to use `rm -i` or why I have chosen to pick gvfs-trash and trash-cli. I simply feel it's safer and I will not switch to the original rm. So please don't give answers that directs me to using the original rm.

Comment: Sharing h​o​w​?

Comment: If you want to get a confirmation before deleting, alias `rm='rm -i`. Keep in mind that FAT32 does not support symbolic links.

Comment: `rm='rm -i'` - closing apostroph not to forget. Of course you test it first, though.

Comment: @Ignacio: VM fusion has a sharing folders options. the folder in mac will be exposed as a partition in the virtual machine and it will be mounted at /mnt/hgfs. (Wasn't I clear enough at the bullet points?)

Comment: Only to someone that knows VMFusion.

Comment: You ask for the best way to deal with it, then ask not to be told the half-dozen best ways. If your current method causes a problem, maybe it's not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

gvfs makes many assumptions about the file system. Assumes it can find the size of the file system, not so with two OS's changing it. File moves are instant on a single partition, that it can find the entire partition and where it's mounted.

I can not recommend assuming any trash-can will always truly work on a network drive. To many things are hidden for it to be reliable. The file might be opened somewhere else, without anyway way for the second computer knowing. NFS does most of these things at a cost of speed and security. Even with several compromises, it still makes assumptions.